# Search and export list of available names in AD

Tags: powershell, batch-file, dns, directory, names

I have AD with a lot of computers in it. computer names are made like this: XXXXNNNN (where X=constant part and N=numeric dynamic part of the name). Any thoughts how can I scan names from N=0 --> N=Nmax, and export all unused (free) names to *.txt?

Comment: Use a `for /L` loop to iterate over a series of numbers.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -Like "XXXX*"} -Property * | Select-Object Name |  Format-Table Name -Wrap -Auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[int]$NMax = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like "XXXX*"} | Sort-Object name | select -ExpandProperty name -Last 1).SubString(4, 4)

$i = 0001
while ($i -ne ($NMax+1))
{
    try
    {
        Get-ADComputer ("XXXX"+$($i.ToString("D4"))) | select name | out-null
    }
    catch
    {
        write "No ADComputer with the name: XXXX$($i.ToString("D4"))"
    }
    $i++
}
```